# Glassfishv3 and log4j

Tags: logging, glassfish, log4j, glassfish-3

I´m using glassfishv3 for few days. But i don´t know how to get log4j working with the v3.

In glassfishv2 there was a "System Classpath" field which you could used in order to point to your log4j.properties file.

But in glassfishv3 "System Classpath" is not supported any more.

So where i have to put the log4j.properties file on glassfishv3???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `log4j.properties` is located in the root of the classpath. You can override this location by setting the `log4j.configuration` system property, e.g.

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=my/path/to/log4j.properties
```

So then it can reside anywhere in the classpath you like.

As to how to set system properties in glassfish, I have no idea, but it can't be that hard.

Comment: hmm... thanks for your answer skaffman. I´ve try it out. But after restart of the server there is still the warning "log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly."

Answer (score 1):

**It works** when i copy the log4j.properties file into the /opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/classes folder.

Then it is in the classpath ;)